# How can I add SSL in keycloak in docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssl, certificate, keycloak

I'm having an issue adding SSL certificate to Keycloak that is running on docker. I got an SSL Certificate from AWS EC2 with Load Balancer, but don't know how to add it to Keycloak on docker. I was looking through Google but nothing found yet.

Also when i go to page like: https://stackoverflow.com, the ssl works perfectly. But when I try to open https://stackoverflow.com:8443 (since 8443 is the port of Keycloak) its not working.

Here's the code of Dockerfile of Keycloak:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:4.6.0.Final

WORKDIR /opt/jboss/keycloak

COPY realm-export.json /opt/jboss/keycloak/

EXPOSE 8443

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0", "-Dkeycloak.import=realm-export.json -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING"]
```

And here's the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  keycloak:
    build: "./Keycloak + actibook-app client import"
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-postgres
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=${KEYCLOAK_IMPORT}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSW}
      - POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR= keycloak-postgres
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"

  traefik:
    build: ./traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: Why are you publishing the port 8443? When using a reverse proxy for http/https like _Traefik_ the only public published port should be 80 and 443.  The "backend"-containers should only be accessible on the private network.

Comment: @rckrd well how can I access to keycloak in that port other way?

Comment: @rckrd when you want to login, the app should redirect you to Keycloak login page `https://domain:8443/login`, so I cant do it other way than accessing the current port

Comment: My suggestion is to read up on the purpose of a reverse proxy https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy

Comment: @rckrd yep i did it. But the problem is that I dont know how else can I access to that keycloak service

Comment: I would configure traefik to serve keycloak on a subdomain such as account.example.com . I.e reqs to account.example.com is forwarded on the private network to the container running keycloak

Comment: @rckrd so that would be the only option right? I guess to make that happen i should add `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:account.example.com` at keycloak service label in `docker-compose.yml`?  And then at the domain need to point it to redirect to public ip of the server?

Comment: Yes, sounds like a good solution

Answer (score 4):

You will need to make sure the key file is readable by jboss user inside the docker. Here are some key steps in my solution:
1. get cert/key from let's encrypt.
2. change file mode to 655
3. mount them to keycloak:
      - /opt/www/sso/cert/fullchain.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - /opt/www/sso/cert/privkey.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key
4. launch docker image
5. change file mode back to 600 for the key file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about file permission. In case any one need it, below are the commands that I used to run my keycloak docker:
`chmod 655 /home/test/keycloak.*`
and

`docker run -d --name keycloak --net keycloak-network -p 8443:8443 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin --mount type=bind,source=/home/test/keycloak.key,target=/etc/x509/https/tls.key --mount type=bind,source=/home/test/keycloak.crt,target=/etc/x509/https/tls.crt jboss/keycloak`

Answer (score 3):

README is a good friend - https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/:

> ## Setting up TLS(SSL)
>
> Keycloak image allows you to specify both a private key and a
>   certificate for serving HTTPS. In that case you need to provide two
>   files:
>
> ```
> tls.crt - a certificate
> tls.key - a private key
> ```
>
> Those files need to be mounted in /etc/x509/https directory. The image
>   will automatically convert them into a Java keystore and reconfigure
>   Wildfly to use it.

But that is only Keycloak TLS container configuration. You are using also Traefik, so you may need to configure TLS in Traefik container - it depends on your configuration.

Comment: Do i need to provide these as volumes in `docker-compose.yml` and then call `tls.crt` and `tls.key` each to a file that contains certificate and private key, or should I call them as flags here in DockerFile `CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0", "-Dkeycloak.import=realm-export.json -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING"]`

Comment: The Asker wrote that a load balancer is used. Why would the certificates be configured on keycloak? The ssl should be terminated at the load balancer, right?

Comment: @rckrd well the problem is that, when I'm trying to open '`https://stackoverflow.com:8443` which 8443 port is Keycloak port, the SSL is not working. I guess the Keycloak is generating a self-signed certificate by default

Comment: @rckrd Keycloak is a security/auth component - it is always a good idea to use TLS for communication also behind LB. It is not clear what is a role of Traefik here. Is it a router or LB + where is terminated TLS connection, ....?

Comment: @JanGaraj the person wanted to have the traefik as a reverse proxy implemented

Comment: What made the deal for me was mapping the port 8443 and changing the file permissions to 655 before running the stack. I do believe that the dockerhub lacks the documentation of the SSL mode.

Answer (score 2):

Steps mentioned in [docker documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) are absolutely correct. And same have been quoted by others in above answers. I just want to point out the script which is used to read the mounted certificates & key and then keystores are generated on the fly.

One can refer to the script at path `/opt/jboss/tools/x509.sh` inside the container or refer it from the [github](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/server/tools/x509.sh). This was helpful to me in debugging the same.

One must absolutely make sure that they are uploading the key and certificate to the exact path and folder with appropriate permissions. Also, name of the key should `tls.key` and certificate should be `tls.crt` as same have been hardcoded in the script.

**Bonus**: Same script is used to add CA files to the truststore which is also generated on the fly. Hence, if your keycloak is communicating with other https servers, do not forget to mount root CA files to the keycloak container and pass the environment variable as below.

`X509_CA_BUNDLE=/path/to/root1.pem /path/to/root2.pem`

Also, make sure that the ca files are in PEM format and having appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm below comment rep. level so I'm adding an answer here. My assumption is that all of your components are docker containers.

@Jan Garaj's answer is correct in principle. What's not clear is that the logical routing in your case looks like this (service side):

```
service --> Keyclaok --> traefik --> network/dns --> user/browser
```

The actual routing looks like this (i.e. common bridge docker network assumed):

```
service
   |---------> traefik --> network/dns --> user/browser
keyclaok
```

- Keycloak is creating a self signed cert between itself and Traefik

  - you have to specify a `volumes:` directive in Keyclaok's `docker-compose.yml` file (as mentioned earlier).
- If you just want to test that Keycloak is working you can add `InsecureSkipVerify = true` to the top of your Traefik config file (i.e. `traefik.toml`).
- Once you've established that Keycloak is accessible you should either use the AWS cert-pair or create your own self signed cert (with a personal certificate authority).

  - here's a link that might help you with creating your own certificate authority: (linux based) [Ubuntu: Creating a trusted CA and SAN certificate using OpenSSL – Fabian Lee : Software Architect](https://fabianlee.org/2018/02/17/ubuntu-creating-a-trusted-ca-and-san-certificate-using-openssl-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

Just insert in docker-compose.yml in service keycloak user: root

The keycloak image is installed as root but the execution of the container is done as jboss, but the directory permissions do not allow jboss to create the jks to do https.

If you run the container as root it works.

Another alternative is to create a new image by modifying the permissions of the directories where you store the certificates.

Comment: this will work but there are good reason not to run a container as root: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/why-processes-in-docker-containers-shouldnt-run-as-root/