# bitnami spark docker install packages on the minideb

Tags: docker, debian, bitnami

how to install additional packages in bitnami spark docker image :latest, which comes with a minideb version,

Also I am unable to do sudo su -

```
I have no name!@83b7ecb6a567:/opt/bitnami/spark$ apt install iproute2
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
I have no name!@83b7ecb6a567:/opt/bitnami/spark$ uname -a
Linux 83b7ecb6a567 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 6 15:49:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I have no name!@83b7ecb6a567:/opt/bitnami/spark$ apt-get install net-tools
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
I have no name!@83b7ecb6a567:/opt/bitnami/spark$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the compose file and do a docker-compose up

```
    image: bitnami/spark:2
    user: root

k# apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done

# apt-get install net-tools
Reading package lists... Done
```

[install package on docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870005/how-to-install-ifconfig-command-in-my-ubuntu-docker-image)

[change non root user to root](https://docs.bitnami.com/containers/how-to/work-with-non-root-containers/)

Comment: by adding the line user: root right after the image: directive in the container's docker-compose.yml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913032/how-can-i-add-ssl-in-keycloak-in-docker  comments from @Paco Sanjuan